# Matrix is not getting displayed completely in Latex

Tags: matrices

I am trying to display the matrix in latex document using below code.But the right side of the matrix is not getting displayed completely.Please check this.

```
\[
 M=
\left[ {\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 1.2 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.9 & 0\\
 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.4\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.07 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.07 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array} } \right]
\]
```

Comment: You can (1) reduce the font size; (2) rescale the entire output and make it smaller; or (3) reduce the `\arraycolsep`. It depends on your document or output requirements. Also, rather use `\begin{array}{*{24}{c}}` - it's much less error prone.

Comment: you may also think of using `\begin{smallmatrix}…\end{smallmatrix}`

Comment: another possibility is to pack the array into a `\scalebox` as provided by the `graphicx` package.  however, that could become almost unreadable.  better, i think, to make this into a figure and set it landscape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code shows three possible options:

1. Using `\resizebox` to automatically scale the matrix to have width equal to `\textwidth` (since the matrix is really large, the resulting matrix can be difficult to read).
2. Using `\resizebox` but previously increasing the margins using, for example, the `\adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package; this improves readability, but margins have been partially increased nad this might not be desired.
3. Using the `\resizebox` and the `sidewaysfigure` environment from the rotating package to put the matrix in landscape orientation in a page of its own. This seems to be the best solution.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{changepage}
   \usepackage{rotating}

   \begin{document}

   % requires the graphicx package
   \[
   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    $M=
   \left[ {\begin{array}{*{24}{c}}
    0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 1.2 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.9 & 0\\
    0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.4\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.07 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.07 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0\\
   \end{array} } \right]$
    }
   \]

   % requires the changepage package
   \begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{-3cm}
   \[
   \resizebox{\dimexpr\textwidth+6cm\relax}{!}{%
    $M=
   \left[ {\begin{array}{*{24}{c}}
    0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 1.2 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.9 & 0\\
    0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.4\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.07 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.07 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0\\
   \end{array} } \right]$
    }
   \]
   \end{adjustwidth}

   % requires the rotating package
   \begin{sidewaysfigure}
   \[
   \resizebox{\textheight}{!}{%
    $M=
   \left[ {\begin{array}{*{24}{c}}
    0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 1.2 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0.3 & 0 & 0.9 & 0\\
    0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.95 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0 & 0 & 0.47 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.4\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.07 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.07 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.38 & 0 & 0\\
   \end{array} } \right]$
    }
   \]

   \end{sidewaysfigure}

   \end{document}
   ```

The result showing the three options for comparison:

[image]

Comment: surely better to use `sidewaystable` (rather than ...figure), so that the caption comes out right (even though op didn't mention a caption)